# Keep DIV bottom screen when scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV at bottom footer, I want keep at alway on top and bottom of screen, but only ontop and fix at bottom when position over a pixel (ex: 500px from top to bottom).

if < 500px is nomal DIV, > 500px is fix at bottom.

I have use css but this alway bottom.

```
body {
    margin-bottom:90px;
}

#footer {
    bottom: 0px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a *media query* for that :

*CSS :*

```
#footer {
    top: 0px;  /* you can delete these two lines if you want the position as it is */
    position:fixed;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px){
    #footer { bottom: 0px; }
}
```